# Related content and tagging

Tags: 2010, tagging

Is it possible with SharePoint 2010 Server to have a "Related Content" section on pages, where it automatically pulls in links to other pages that have content tagged together? Is this built-in or an add-on?

So let's say a page is created that has information about "recipes", another page uses the same tag "recipes", and we can have a "Related Content" web part that displays a certain number of links to other pages that have the same tag(s).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently played around with this product for a project I was working on, but it's part of a bigger suite which had components the customer didn't need:

http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/SharePoint-Related-Content-Web-Part.aspx

May be worth evaluating.

At the same time I came across this blog post on how to accomplish this OOB (it more or less met the customer's requirements):

http://sharepintblog.com/2011/05/27/use-sharepoint-keywords-and-metadata-to-display-related-content/

Comment: Loving that second link

Comment: Very nice. Thank you, Rob, especially for the second link. Looked all over and didn't see that. We'd like to go with built-in and free solutions first.

Comment: Yep...good stuff...stumbled across that one looking for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Although Rob D'Oria provides a *very* good solution, please consider the use of sharepoint search, and especially federated search too. You can enrich your related content cross-site collection content, content from other systems that is indexed or even content from the internet, like google, wikipedia, bing, twitter, you name it!

Comment: Thanks, Bas. We're implementing SharePoint enterprise search and will of course have that feature available to the users.